# How to use existing Eclipse MAT indexes for interactive analysis

Tags: memory, heap-memory, analysis, eclipse-mat

I am attempting to use Eclipse MAT (Memory Analysis Toolkit) to analyze some rather large heap dumps (~2G).  My laptop unfortunately has 32bit Windows, and MAT runs out of heap space @ 1.4G allocated heap.  I was successful in running the heap indexer from the command line on a large, headless 64bit box.  However, I am unable to convince MAT to import these index files from a directory on my laptop so that I may investigate the heap interactively.  All my attempts at loading the heap (with the index files alongside it) have resulted in MAT deciding to re-parse the heap file instead of using the existing indexes.  Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy *all* files which are present in that directory to your laptop. I've done this successfully many times.  I run the analyser on the server using

```
/opt/mat/MemoryAnalyzer -consolelog -application org.eclipse.mat.api.parse "$@" org.eclipse.mat.api:suspects org.eclipse.mat.api:top_components
```

This allows me to open the heap dump and then open the stored reports.

Comment: Thanks.  I need to try this out before awarding you the bounty, but it looks promising!

Comment: These options are not really necessary

Comment: @kohlerm : not necessary, but will insure that the reports are pre-built, and not run on the lower-memory machine.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to copy all the files that have the same file name prefix to the new location. 
It's really as simple as that.